# disconnect filepicker

Tags: filepicker.io

I have disconnect filepicker when I close the session in my web application, with the intention that if another user starts session in the same PC , he will should starts newly login in the services of filepicker(for example dropbox), but I have not found a way to disconnect filepicker.

I appreciate any help and guidance on this issue.

Comment: Without clearing the cookies or instructing the user to manually de-auth the services they have used there is no way to do this.